# Struts 2 <s:if> tag How to get action name to be evaluated in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

Now I can get any desired results if I use the `<s:if>` tag in Struts2

```
    <s:if test="status==1">
         //do some stuff
    </s:if>
```

but I don't know how to get the action currently executed, I am expecting like

```
    <s:if test="action==addaction">
         //do some stuff
    </s:if>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get action name from the context

```
<s:if test="#context['struts.actionMapping'].name=='addaction'">
   do some stuff
</s:if>
```

Comment: for struts 2.3.34 and above use: `#request['struts.actionMapping'].name`

Answer (score 5):

Since Struts version 2.3.34 and 2.5.13 `#context` is not available anymore because of security reasons (see [WW-4852](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4852))
As a workaround you can use `#request` which is documented [here](https://struts.apache.org/docs/ognl.html)

```
<s:if test="#request['struts.actionMapping'].name=='addaction'">
   do some stuff
</s:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<s:if test='%{com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext.name=="YourActionName"}'>
     //do some stuff
</s:if>
```