# How to get the Action name in JSP even if it's empty?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, struts-action

I am new to java. I tried to search around but did not find anything similar to my question.

I have list items in menu (`<ul>`-s and `<li>`-s) I want to add the `active` class in `<li>` tag depending on the action's name to make the specific menu item active.

For this I have used this piece of code

```jsp
${request.context['struts.actionMapping'].name}
```

This piece of code is working fine on all pages except on page were action name is `""` i.e empty string. The empty string check or null check is not working where action name is just `""`

```jsp
<s:set var="action">${request.context['struts.actionMapping'].name}</s:set>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="<s:if test="%{#action == ''}">active</s:if>">
        <s:a href="/crudoperation">Dashboard</s:a>
    </li>
    <li class="<s:if test="%{#action == 'add'}">active</s:if>">
        <s:url var="addUrl" action="add"/>
        <s:a href="%{addUrl}">Add Student Profile</s:a>
    </li>
    <li class="<s:if test="%{#action == 'edit'}">active</s:if>">
        <s:url var="editUrl" action="edit"/>
        <s:a href="%{editUrl}">Edit Profile</s:a>
    </li>
    <li class="<s:if test="%{#action == 'view'}">active</s:if>">
        <s:url var="viewUrl" action="view"/>
        <s:a href="%{viewUrl}">View Profile</s:a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my struts.xml

```jsp
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">

        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles"
                class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>

        <action name="" class="com.javaguy.struts2.IndexAction">
            <result name="master" type="tiles">master</result>
        </action>

        <action name="add" class="com.javaguy.struts2.AddAction">
            <result name="add" type="tiles">add</result>
        </action>

        <action name="edit" class="com.javaguy.struts2.EditAction">
            <result name="edit" type="tiles">edit</result>
        </action>

        <action name="view" class="com.javaguy.struts2.ViewAction">
            <result name="view" type="tiles">view</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: Empty action? Why? Use `<default-action-ref>`.

Comment: Maybe he wants to catch only the empty action and not every non-matching URL. There is also the `"*"` trick, and BTW the best would be to use a non-empty name, but I guess the whole point is a bit broad

Comment: How one can call empty action at all? Something like `/.action`.

Comment: The correct syntax to get the action in the JSP is now `#request['struts.actionMapping'].name`  (not `request.context...`) - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46111170/1005607

Answer (score 2):

In case of empty action name the `${request.context['struts.actionMapping'].name}` will produce emptiness in `<s:set>` tag body which is equal to `<s:set var="some"></s:set>` and that will assign top object from the value stack to `some` variable. Usually top object in the value stack is action class instance. So you get something like `com.javaguy.struts2.IndexAction@4349f7db` in your variable instead of empty string.

To get an empty action name just use OGNL in `<s:set>` tag.

```
<s:set var="some" value="#request.context['struts.actionMapping'].name" />
```

Also like Andrea already mentioned avoid using keywords (such as `action`) in your variables.

Comment: A *little* side effect of mixing EL with Struts tags :D

Comment: @YasirWali: Do you have any further questions regarding this problem? If not, don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you.

Comment: The correct syntax to get the action in the JSP is now `#request['struts.actionMapping'].name` (not `request.context...`) - see stackoverflow.com/a/46111170/1005607